# How to show the users a message when they click submit button and the input field is empty on react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to show an error message to users when they press a button with empty input fields (something like "YOU HAVE TO FILL ALL REQUIRED FIELDS"). This is my code:

Here is the Form component that has the input fields and submitt button and you can see the component has props:

```
export default function Form({ loading, onSubmit }) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
  const [slug, setSlug] = useState('')
  const [preAmble, setPreAmble] = useState('')
  const [slogan, setSlogan] = useState('')
  const [box, setBox] = useState('')
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  // Function for å håndtere brukerinput

  const inputValiderin = (title, slug, preAmble, slogan, box)
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (inputValiderin.length === 0) {
      return
    }
    await onSubmit({ title, slug, preAmble, slogan, box })
    navigate('/')
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h2 className="m-10 text-xl font-bold">Ny tjeneste</h2>
      <form
        className="ml-10 flex flex-col"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        method="POST"
      >
        <label htmlFor="title" className="my-6 flex flex-col">
          <span className="font-bold">Tittel*</span>
          <input
            className="w-1/2 rounded-lg bg-gray-100 "
            onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)}
            value={title}
            data-testid="form_title"
            type="text"
            name="title"
            id="title"
          />
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="slug" className="my-3 flex flex-col">
          <span className="font-bold">Slug*</span>
          <input
            className="w-1/2 rounded-lg bg-gray-100 "
            onChange={(event) => setSlug(event.target.value)}
            value={slug}
            data-testid="form_slug"
            type="text"
            name="slug"
            id="slug"
          />
        </label>
        <button
          className="float-left w-1/4 rounded-lg bg-green-700 py-2 font-medium text-white"
          type="submit"
        >
          {loading ? 'Sender...' : 'Lag skjema'}
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

and this is the main component that renders the changes

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Form from '../components/Form'
import { sendForm } from '../lib/sendForm'
// Fil som lager "ny tjeneste" side og håndtåring av bruker input
export default function Create() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false)

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    setLoading(true)
    setError(false)
    setSuccess(false)

    try {
      await sendForm(data)
      setSuccess(true)
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Form loading={loading} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
      {success ? (
        <p className="m-10 text-2xl font-semibold">Skjema er sendt</p>
      ) : null}
      {error ? { error } : null}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is have a status state for each input, like this:

```
const [emailStatus, setStatusEmail] = useState(false)
```

Then, once the text is changed, all you need to do is have a function that handles the text change:

```
const changeHandler = (value) => {
          if (value.length != 0) {
               setStatusEmail(true)
          }
     }
```

This will check if the input isn't empty, of course you would need to then do your verifications to check if the input is actually valid. Once the user clicks the submit button, you need to check if the status is true, if it's false, there's a wrong or empty input:

```
if(emailStatus == false) {
    Alert.alert(
                "ERROR",
                "Something went wrong... Please make sure you have inserted all data correctly.",
                [{
                    text: "OK",
                    style: "ok",
                }])
}
```